# Three.js error to try load scene with THREE.SceneLoader()

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a three.js scene (THREE.REVISION == 69) :

```
var Cena = new THREE.Scene(); // init scene
```

In this scene I have grid, light, cam, and many cubes.

I save all scene in the variable *sceneJSON*:

```
var exporter = new THREE.SceneExporter();
var scene = Cena;
var sceneJson = JSON.stringify(exporter.parse(scene));
```

When I try load/import the scene with this code:

```
var sceneLoader = new THREE.SceneLoader();
sceneLoader.parse(JSON.parse(json), function (e) {scene = e.scene;}, '.');
```

I receive this error:

```
TypeError: light.target.set is not a function
```

How to fix this?

Follow JSON:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "version": 4.3,
        "type": "Object",
        "generator": "ObjectExporter"
    },
    "geometries": [
        {
            "uuid": "9848FD0D-E02D-4D2E-BB80-93CD4CA27AFF",
            "type": "Geometry",
            "data": {
                "vertices": [-100,0,-100,100,0,-100,-100,0,-100,-100,0,100,-100,0,-90,100,0,-90,-90,0,-100,-90,0,100,-100,0,-80,100,0,-80,-80,0,-100,-80,0,100,-100,0,-70,100,0,-70,-70,0,-100,-70,0,100,-100,0,-60,100,0,-60,-60,0,-100,-60,0,100,-100,0,-50,100,0,-50,-50,0,-100,-50,0,100,-100,0,-40,100,0,-40,-40,0,-100,-40,0,100,-100,0,-30,100,0,-30,-30,0,-100,-30,0,100,-100,0,-20,100,0,-20,-20,0,-100,-20,0,100,-100,0,-10,100,0,-10,-10,0,-100,-10,0,100,-100,0,0,100,0,0,0,0,-100,0,0,100,-100,0,10,100,0,10,10,0,-100,10,0,100,-100,0,20,100,0,20,20,0,-100,20,0,100,-100,0,30,100,0,30,30,0,-100,30,0,100,-100,0,40,100,0,40,40,0,-100,40,0,100,-100,0,50,100,0,50,50,0,-100,50,0,100,-100,0,60,100,0,60,60,0,-100,60,0,100,-100,0,70,100,0,70,70,0,-100,70,0,100,-100,0,80,100,0,80,80,0,-100,80,0,100,-100,0,90,100,0,90,90,0,-100,90,0,100,-100,0,100,100,0,100,100,0,-100,100,0,100],
                "normals": [],
                "faces": []
            }
        },
        {
            "uuid": "DCC723E0-C1E0-4CB4-B047-56AF8FCDD3E2",
            "type": "BoxGeometry",
            "width": 4,
            "height": 4,
            "depth": 4
        },
        {
            "uuid": "AE0EA8E4-47AC-4D29-AD68-CE00181F9E21",
            "type": "BoxGeometry",
            "width": 4,
            "height": 4,
            "depth": 4
        },
        {
            "uuid": "0AE6C8FD-83BD-4946-BFCB-F767B01FE579",
            "type": "BoxGeometry",
            "width": 4,
            "height": 4,
            "depth": 4
        },
        {
            "uuid": "6B40660B-CF8B-4CB8-AD55-E0F959C5979C",
            "type": "BoxGeometry",
            "width": 4,
            "height": 4,
            "depth": 4
        }],
    "materials": [
        {
            "uuid": "F174D367-B14B-47C9-9818-1D1A62540882",
            "type": "LineBasicMaterial"
        },
        {
            "uuid": "83848195-1452-40DA-827F-A498C1D870F9",
            "type": "MeshPhongMaterial",
            "color": 16777215,
            "ambient": 16777215,
            "emissive": 0,
            "specular": 1118481,
            "shininess": 30,
            "opacity": 0.8,
            "transparent": true
        },
        {
            "uuid": "37C5C4FD-3402-4FE4-877D-E66BD18D797E",
            "type": "MeshPhongMaterial",
            "color": 16777215,
            "ambient": 16777215,
            "emissive": 0,
            "specular": 1118481,
            "shininess": 30,
            "opacity": 0.8,
            "transparent": true
        },
        {
            "uuid": "FC6E4C1C-8191-4CE9-B687-A29C13EA9400",
            "type": "MeshPhongMaterial",
            "color": 16777215,
            "ambient": 16777215,
            "emissive": 0,
            "specular": 1118481,
            "shininess": 30,
            "opacity": 0.8,
            "transparent": true
        },
        {
            "uuid": "CE06172B-3277-4B91-B113-3BC45963EE2E",
            "type": "MeshPhongMaterial",
            "color": 16777215,
            "ambient": 16777215,
            "emissive": 0,
            "specular": 1118481,
            "shininess": 30,
            "opacity": 0.8,
            "transparent": true
        }],
    "object": {
        "uuid": "FDF89002-FA43-4B30-BEB1-8548BFF8592D",
        "type": "Scene",
        "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
        "children": [
            {
                "uuid": "5E79AA2B-C280-4A2B-9312-440F701CBEE3",
                "type": "PerspectiveCamera",
                "fov": 50,
                "aspect": 1,
                "near": 0.1,
                "far": 2000,
                "matrix": [0.8944271802902222,-1.3716013880227251e-9,-0.4472135901451111,0,-0.15064871311187744,0.9415544867515564,-0.3012974262237549,0,0.4210759699344635,0.3368607759475708,0.842151939868927,0,50,50,100,1]
            },
            {
                "uuid": "3984192A-DD7F-4689-A076-6770131B23AD",
                "type": "Line",
                "name": "Grid",
                "geometry": "9848FD0D-E02D-4D2E-BB80-93CD4CA27AFF",
                "material": "F174D367-B14B-47C9-9818-1D1A62540882",
                "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
            },
            {
                "uuid": "ACB0E066-532C-4444-9FA7-181C76BAAB95",
                "type": "AmbientLight",
                "color": 5592405,
                "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
            },
            {
                "uuid": "FFDE61E5-CA82-4BC9-B406-1B7A9006D1DD",
                "type": "DirectionalLight",
                "color": 16777215,
                "intensity": 0.8,
                "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0.5773502588272095,0.5773502588272095,0.5773502588272095,1]
            },
            {
                "uuid": "A94B706F-7329-48A5-9CF8-040795E57314",
                "type": "SpotLight",
                "color": 16777215,
                "intensity": 0.6,
                "distance": 0,
                "angle": 1.0471975511965976,
                "exponent": 10,
                "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,-30,30,-100,1]
            },
            {
                "uuid": "6608DD55-558B-4718-B953-F686D42B3744",
                "type": "Mesh",
                "geometry": "DCC723E0-C1E0-4CB4-B047-56AF8FCDD3E2",
                "material": "83848195-1452-40DA-827F-A498C1D870F9",
                "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,-9.931706428527832,0,-9.857349395751953,1]
            },
            {
                "uuid": "25A41D96-791D-4FBE-9CB9-5AEC0ECBE991",
                "type": "Mesh",
                "geometry": "AE0EA8E4-47AC-4D29-AD68-CE00181F9E21",
                "material": "37C5C4FD-3402-4FE4-877D-E66BD18D797E",
                "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,2.9669816493988037,0,5.327826976776123,1]
            },
            {
                "uuid": "B6FE254F-BCA8-41B1-A63C-4CB7CAA6F734",
                "type": "Mesh",
                "geometry": "0AE6C8FD-83BD-4946-BFCB-F767B01FE579",
                "material": "FC6E4C1C-8191-4CE9-B687-A29C13EA9400",
                "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1.5996896028518677,0,-7.717252254486084,1]
            },
            {
                "uuid": "0EFA29CB-D365-4942-B54B-D43FFFB22D3E",
                "type": "Mesh",
                "geometry": "6B40660B-CF8B-4CB8-AD55-E0F959C5979C",
                "material": "CE06172B-3277-4B91-B113-3BC45963EE2E",
                "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,8.166288375854492,0,14.097293853759766,1]
            }]
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't supplied the code where the error actually originates, but it's quite clear from the error supplied what the problem is and where to look for it. There's no such method: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Lights/Light. If you can supply the JSON that generates your scene, it should help.

Comment: I would like to upload the file here, but do not know how to attach here at stackoverflow. Can you help me in this regard?

Comment: Simply edit your question and post the code into the block and format it appropriately, either using the {} tool in the editor, or do it yourself by putting four spaces prior to each code line, with additional spaces for indentation of code, as required.

Comment: You'll need to include the JSON in your question, not a link to it.

Comment: Done. I had to reduce the size of the JSON file, it had more than 600Kb.